# What Google API can let me work with domain shared contacts in C#

Tags: c#, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I have been looking into the Google APIs as I have special requirements to work with domain shared contacts with C#...

I wonder if Google.GData.Contacts will let me do what I want with shared contacts?

I checked the classes in Google.APIs.Admin.Directory but I could not find anything related to domain shared contacts...

Appreciate your help
Regards

Answer (score 2):

The Domain Shared Contacts API is the same API endpoint as the Contacts API. You just pass the domain in instead of the username/"default" in the URL.

Comment: Cool! Have you had this running in prod? Is this documented somewhere (even informally)? FYI I am still using the [Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/)

Comment: The content in that documentation is basically the same as the general [Contacts API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) except with the domain shown as the username. It's never been clear to me why it's been treated externally as a separate API.